Reduce size on macbook on external drive
I have a macbook and I was thinking of what to do to reduce the size on it.
People suggest to use brew cask to install some apps on the external drive.

I did that but for some apps like discord, if an update is required, as soon as i open it it get removed from my system. Is there a way to auto update before I open it?

Should I also create a symlink on Application Support folder from my external drive. If that helps, how do I need to do it?



The question is not 100% clear tbh!
I'm guessing you want to "resize" the drive, or?

I think it's pretty clear, I want to install as many apps as I can on my external drive so that I can save up space in my internal SSD
